# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': There is no Workflow App Part registered

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-addin, custom

When creating SharePoint Addin in SharePoint 2016 after creating Initialization form for Sequential Workflow and for testing App deploying the App on server giving error.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': There is no Workflow App Part registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to run this script in SharePoint Management Shell

```
$WmsSap = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$WmsSap.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment()
```

Reffered from this [link](https://gerardbeckerleg.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-there-is-no-workflow-app-part-registered/) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure SharePoint server have the WorkFlow Manager installed and configured.

WorkFlow Manager also requires ServiceBus to be installed

Then run the following commands in the SharePoint Management Shell:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'http://localhost:24000' -WorkflowHostUri 'https://localhost:12290' -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
$WmsSap = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$WmsSap.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment()
```